# How to make text evenly spaced apart in a div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: Text is not evenly spaced apart]

I would like the 3 groups of text:
To be evenly spaced apart over the image.
Not overflow past the image when the page is reduced in width.

Does anyone have any ideas, please?

The image is placed inside a flexbox.
I have tried adding top % to the code, however, when I reduce the page width, the text then overflows the image, as shown.

This is my HTML code:

```
<!-- mountain background -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="item2">
    <h2 class="mtn1">A 44-letter alphabet.</h2>
    <h2 class="mtn2">
      A phonetically <br />
      consistent language.
    </h2>
    <h2 class="mtn3">
      A determined teacher <br />
      you can count on
    </h2>
    <img
      class="img4"
      src="pictures/output-onlinepngtools.png"
      alt=""
      style="width: 100%"
    />
  </div>
  <!-- mountain end -->
</div>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
/* mountain photo */
.img4 {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item2 {
  width: 100vw;
}

.mtn1 {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 46%;
  font-family: "LiberationSansRegular";
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 70px;
}

.mtn2 {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  font-family: "LiberationSansRegular";
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 70px;
}

.mtn3 {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 85%;
  font-family: "LiberationSansRegular";
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 70px;
}
```

Comment: Instead of absolutely positioning three elements separately, you should probably stick those into a flexbox container, and work with `justify-content` to space them over the _available_ height.

Comment: Also, I think you need a media-queries for smaller screens to make text smaller to let it fit in the picture

Comment: Exactly, the text overlaps. I'd be better use `overflow: scroll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need flex box for this.
You can work it out with `background-image`.

```css
/* mountain photo */
.img4 {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/23/13/48/beach-1852945_960_720.jpg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.item2 {
  width: 100vw;
}

.mtn1 {
  font-family: "LiberationSansRegular";
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 70px;
}

.mtn2 {
  font-family: "LiberationSansRegular";
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 70px;
}

.mtn3 {
  font-family: "LiberationSansRegular";
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 70px;
}
```

```html
<!-- mountain background -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="item2">
    <h2 class="mtn1">A 44-letter alphabet.</h2>
    <h2 class="mtn2">
      A phonetically <br />
      consistent language.
    </h2>
    <h2 class="mtn3">
      A determined teacher <br />
      you can count on
    </h2>
  </div>
  <!-- mountain end -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a more minimalistic approach, just to show how it works:
Only one class, and two attributes needed.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>This</p>
  <p>is evenly</p>
  <p>spaced content</p>
  <p>with minimal</p>
  <p>styling</p>
</div>
```

if you want a specific distance you have two approaches.
You either set a height on the parent, or you set `gap: 25px;` if you want a spacing of 25px. Remember that some elements have margin/paddings, that might interfere, so you will have to either remove those or take them into account.

If you want the text to adjust its size, I think you are best off with a media query. This will be in relation to the window however, and not the size of the box/parent.
So you could use percentages... and play around to see if you find a size that fits what you need.